# The meaning of export command in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

What does `export` mean in Ubuntu? For example:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/src/hive/build/dist/bin/
```

Comment: It's a bash command; `info bash` for more information. And it's "Ubuntu", not "ubunto".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This means, that your path is extended with `/usr/src/hive/build/dist/bin/`. Normally /usr/bin, /bin, /usr/sbin, etc are "in your path". If you have a programm /bin/sh, you can just type sh to run it. If you have a program in `/usr/src/hive/build/dist/bin/appname` you can just run appname to execute it.

Answer (score 40):

[export](http://ss64.com/bash/export.html) is a command in the Bash shell language.  When used to set a variable, as in your example, the variable (PATH) will be visible ("exported to") any subprocesses started 
from that instance of Bash.  Without the export command, the variable will not exist
in the subprocess.

Comment: but when I run this command,nothing occured.should I see a change when I run this command?

Comment: If you do `echo $PATH`, you will see that the dir that you have exported is in the `PATH`. Don't forget that if you want to add this dir to your path in a permanent way you need to put the export in your `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: No nothing happens at first sight, but you can just run any program in this directory like I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: what is difference between **export PATH=$PATH:.**  and  **PATH=$PATH:.**

Answer (score 3):

It sets the environment variable `PATH` to the value of whatever `PATH` currently is plus the new path appended to it.

Comment: should I see something in this path**/usr/src/hive/build/dist/bin/**

Comment: Are you asking if there should be contents in that directory?

Comment: yes,This command makes new directory in this path?

Comment: It doesn't create a directory on the filesystem if that's what you're asking. It appends that directory to the `PATH` env variable, so then you may call any commands in that directory without typing out the full path. If there's a `/usr/src/hive/build/dist/bin/some_program` in that directory, once you add the directory to the `PATH` variable, you can just call `some_program` w/o the full path.