# XDebug: how to debug remote console application?

Tags: command-line-interface, xdebug, phpstorm

I have read this docs: http://xdebug.org/docs/remote

I can debug my web application.
But the debugger doesn't launch for console command.

My .ini file for XDebug (it works):

```
$ cat /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/xdebug.ini
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626/xdebug.so
xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
```

.ini file for `cli` is the same.

Also I tried to add `export XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=PHPSTORM remote_enable=1 remote_connect_back=1"` before debugging, but it didn't help.

How can I enable it?

Comment: Did you check [this blog post](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2012/03/new-in-4-0-easier-debugging-of-remote-php-command-line-scripts/) for the instructions?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Short answer:

We need to set 2 environment variables, these **two** lines:

```
export PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName={SERVER NAME IN PHP STORM}"
export XDEBUG_CONFIG="remote_host=$(echo $SSH_CLIENT | awk '{print $1}') idekey=PHPSTORM"
```

**Updated:**
Good IDE (e.g. PhpStorm) will do it for you, just set PHP interpreter to remote one.

Comment: The second line should be enough.

Comment: In my case the first line was also needed.

Comment: I tried to put second line to `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`, but since it was weird and nothing worked, I googled for "Ubuntu [export](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10841837/the-meaning-of-export-command-in-ubuntu)"  and learned that it should be run in ternminal before running php script. It's not obvious from your answer to your own question.

Comment: In my case the first line was needed. For the 2nd line I've used the settings in the php.ini. Also remote_host set to my client IP (which is external IP) didn't work as the connection went through the internet and I had to use reverse SSH tunnel. It should work though if you (or your router with port forwarding) have a public IP and firewall configured.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @DmitryR for the answer!

But, to avoid exporting XDEBUG_CONFIG each time I open my console, I've added second line (it was enough for me) to my

**~/.bashrc file**

```
export XDEBUG_CONFIG="remote_host=$(echo $SSH_CLIENT | awk '{print $1}') idekey=PHPSTORM"
```