# How to initiate php-cli script xdebug session in netbeans under windows?

Tags: php, xdebug, remote-debugging

Would like to debug php cli script in netbeans under windows. All the necessary xdebug config has been done. I am sure netbeans started to support cli debugging from 6.3, am using 7.3. But it don't seems to be working. Already selected the run configuration in project properties.

Answer (score 0):

Be carefull with Xdebug params, because in Windows there are two php.ini files: one for WAMP (for example) and second for PHP-CLI.

More information at:
[Debugging php-cli scripts with xdebug and netbeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944880/debugging-php-cli-scripts-with-xdebug-and-netbeans)