# Debugging console script over vagrant ssh

Tags: php, netbeans, ssh, vagrant, xdebug

I need to debug a console script run from within my development VM (because of different machine state).

I'm using Netbeans, and I can debug scripts called from the browser just fine.

How do you achieve this, is this possible?

I tried [Debugging php-cli scripts with xdebug and netbeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944880/debugging-php-cli-scripts-with-xdebug-and-netbeans), but I think this applies only to running the script locally.

My current xdebug configuration:

```
[XDEBUG]
xdebug.max_nesting_level=200
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.idekey=netbeans-xdebug
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.collect_params=4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, following this https://www.adayinthelifeof.nl/2012/12/20/debugging-remote-cli-with-phpstorm/, I found out that you need to specify the remote host.

Xdebug must know where to send the data to.

I ended up editing my xdebug configuration to look like this:

```
[XDEBUG]
xdebug.max_nesting_level=200
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.idekey=netbeans-xdebug
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.collect_params=4

xdebug.remote_host=HOST_IP #changed this, removed remote_autostart
```

So now you just have to turn debugging on in Netbeans and run `export XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=netbeans-xdebug"` in your VM's console.

Next run the script you want to debug.

Comment: And this may help in finding a value for `HOST-IP`: http://superuser.com/questions/310697/connect-to-the-host-machine-from-a-virtualbox-guest-os